# Inno Setup: Install in 2 other places

Tags: installation, components, inno-setup

I am really new in this Inno Setup and I would really be glad if someone could help me.

I use Inno Setup to Install a bunch of services.

I needed to add more 2 different services to one component.
each service has other DestDir but both in the same component.
This I already done,
But now I need to install each service in a different direction dependently to the DestDir.
I know where to but I don't know how.

I was suggest to do a batch file that will automatically change Directions.
But I don't know what to write there.

Comment: What do you mean by "different directions" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey,
After some research and work I understood that I need to put 2 items as a child type.
As a child I can control where they will be put.
I also put those children in False Enabled Position so I just need to pick the parent and I pick the both children.